# safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid

Tags: javascript, ios, share

Есть приложение на `ios` которое слушает определенную схему `url`, если в браузере сафари открыть кастомный url, который слушает приложение(`myapp://en/news?id=2`), то приложение открывается, но если же приложение не открывается то появляется вот такая ошибка`safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid`

> стандартное ios решение через Universal Links нельзя использовать так
>   как в поддержке версии с ios 6
>
> пример как человек [решал](https://blog.branch.io/ios-9.2-redirection-update-uri-scheme-and-universal-links) эту ошибку, но мне не помогло

Comment: а какое ожидаемое поведение?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Ожидаемое поведение, это человек проходит по ссылке, если приложение установлено то оно открывается, если приложения нет, то открывается веб страница 

Решение:  для iOS 9-10 использовали Universal Links а для версий ниже js сриппт 
Ниже прикладываю скрипт,

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    var protocolToReplace = "http:";
        if (window.location.protocol == "https:") protocolToReplace = "https:";
        if ("standalone" in window.navigator || window.navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) // определяем платформу
        {
            function tryOpenApp() {
                var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                iframe.style.border = "none";
                iframe.style.width = "1px";
                iframe.style.height = "1px";
                iframe.src = "mycustomscheme://projectDomain.com" + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
                var url = "mycustomscheme://projectDomain.com" + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
                document.body.appendChild(iframe);

                String.prototype.format = String.prototype.f = function(){
                    var args = arguments;
                    return this.replace(/\{(\d+)}/g, function(m,n){
                        return args[n] ? args[n] : m;
                    });
                };

                var meta = document.createElement('meta');
                meta.httpEquiv = "refresh";
                var pathname = window.location.pathname.slice(14);
                url = protocolToReplace + "//www.projectDomain.com" + pathname + window.location.search;
                meta.content = "1; url={0}".f(url);
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);

            }
        }
  </script>
```

Comment: не забудьте принять